# Neural network - Matrix problems in python

Tags: python, matrix, neural-network, linear-algebra, matrix-multiplication

Im playing around with a simple neural network, specifically this tutorial https://stevenmiller888.github.io/mind-how-to-build-a-neural-network/ , and im getting some problems when doing backpropagation. My matrices won't match when backpropagating for the initial input weights.

I guess its a simple linear algebra problem. However, i wonder if the programming language in the tutorial confuses me. Or i could be the problem occured much earlier.

If anybody has any ideas what i might do wrong please let me know!

My Code

```
import numpy as np
inputM = np.matrix([
[0,1],
[1,0],
[1,1],
[0,0]
])

outputM = np.matrix([
[0],
[0],
[1],
[1]
])


neurons = 3 
mu, sigma = 0, 0.1 # mean and standard deviation
weights = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, len(inputM.T) * neurons)
weightsMatrix = np.matrix(weights).reshape(3,2)
weights = np.matrix(weights)

#Forward
inputHidden = inputM * weightsMatrix.T
hiddenLayerLog = 1 / (1 + np.exp(inputHidden))
hiddenWeights = np.random.normal(mu, sigma, neurons)[np.newaxis, :]
sumOfHiddenLayer = np.sum(hiddenWeights + hiddenLayerLog,  axis=1)

predictedOutput = 1 / (1 + np.exp(sumOfHiddenLayer))
residual = outputM - predictedOutput
logDerivative = 1 / (1 + np.exp(sumOfHiddenLayer)) * (1 - 1 / (1 + np.exp(sumOfHiddenLayer))).T
deltaOutputSum = logDerivative * residual

#Backward
deltaWeights = deltaOutputSum / hiddenLayerLog
newHiddenWeights = hiddenWeights - deltaWeights
deltaHiddenSum = (deltaOutputSum / hiddenWeights)
deltaHiddenSum = deltaHiddenSum.T * (1 / (1 + np.exp(inputHidden))) * (1 - 1 / (1 + np.exp(inputHidden))).T
newInputWeights = np.array(deltaHiddenSum) / np.array(inputM)
```

Comment: I think you'd be better off defining a single sigmoid function and calling it as-needed. And I think your current sigmoids needs to negate (have a negative sign) in the exp part.

Comment: @Jarad Thanks, you are right about the neg in sigmoid. I wrote the sigmoid prime out, to ease my lin alg logic. However, none of it solves the problem.

Comment: Ok, clearly this is a broadcast Error. Since plenty of questions have been asked about this im closing the question. Thanks